# How to graph absolute value equations that are not functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Graph $|x + 1| + |y - 2| = 1 $

The graph should be a parallelogram, so it is not a function.  How do you graph this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we isolate $|y-2|$, then we get 
$$|x+1|+|y-2|=1 \Rightarrow |y-2|=1-|x+1|.$$
Now we can apply the definition of absolute value,
$$
|y-2|=
\begin{cases}
\,\,\,\,(y-2) \quad \operatorname{if} \,\,(y-2) \geq 0 \\
-(y-2) \quad\operatorname{if} \,\,(y-2) <0.
\end{cases}
$$
So this gives rise to two equations for you to solve for $y$, namely,
$$
\begin{align*}
(y-2)&=1-|x+1| \\
-(y-2)&=1-|x+1|.
\end{align*}
$$
All that is left for you to do is solve both of these absolute value equations for $y$, and then plot them.

There is a domain restriction due to the absolute value definition. For the first equation, since $(y-2) \geq 0$, 
$$1-|x+1|\geq 0 \Rightarrow |x+1|\leq 1 \Rightarrow -2 \leq x \leq 0.$$

For the second equation, since $(y-2)<0$, $-(y-2)>0$, thus
$$1-|x+1|>0  \Rightarrow |x+1|<1 \Rightarrow -2<x<0.$$

It is this domain restriction that makes your parallelogram pop out of the picture.

I suspect you will be ok at this point, but let us know if your path is still unclear.